# How to get start of week in Influx QL?

Tags: influxdb, influxql

I need to write an flux string in such a way as to get data for a week, but not the `|> range(start: -1w)`, but the calendar week, that is, in my case - 02.10.2023 00:00:00.
It would also be interesting to know how to get data from the beginning of a calendar month/quarter/year.

I tried using
`|> range(start: date.truncate(t: now(), unit: 1w))`
`|> range(start: -1w)`
but I get either the start of the current day or the start of the day that was 7 days ago.
I also tried to use `date.add()` in combination with `date.weekDay()`, but I got an error because the `d:` parameter expects Duration, not the number of days.
I need the calendar start of the week.

Comment: After searching for an answer on the Internet, I found that `date.truncate(t: now(), unit: 1w)` does almost what I need, the only problem is that the beginning of the week is Thursday, and I need Monday. I also found a tip to use timeShift, but I didn't understand exactly how to do it.

Comment: It seems to me like you are using flux, not InfluxQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, combination of methods `date.truncate` and `timeShift` helped me to solve my problem.

```
import "date"
   from(bucket: "training")
  |> range(start: date.truncate(t: -1y, unit: 1w))
  |> aggregateWindow(every: 1w, fn: sum, createEmpty: true)
  |> timeShift(duration: -3d)
  |> fill(column: "_value", value: 0.0)
```